# I still get permission denied from time to time even if I use `core.sharedrepository=group`

Tags: git

```
$ git config --get core.sharedrepository
group
$ stat -c "%a" .git/FETCH_HEAD
644
```

The permission is apparently wrong: it need to be 664 in order to make it group shared

**update**

I did the extra steps already. all dirs in it have correct permission 2775. Aso I did the `chmod -R g+rwX .` before too. It worked at the beginning, no matter who did the git pull/commit for a while. Just after sometime, the .git/FETCH_HEAD become 644 and we do not know why

Is this a bug or is there some configuration I missed?

Comment: a. What's the value for `umask` in your shell ? b. if you set the umask by hand, e.g : `umask 0002`, do you see the correct access rights for `.git/FETCH_HEAD` after running `git fetch` ?

Comment: I checked `umask 0002`

Answer (score 4):

Git doesn't automatically set group or permission on

```
git config core.sharedRepository group
```

This is a list of commands you're recommended to run after setting `sharedRepository` to `group`:

```
# Fix group
chgrp -R <group> . # Use desired group name

# Fix file/directory permissions throughout the entire tree
chmod -R ug+rwX . # Please note **uppercase** X

# Make FS to inherit group on creating subdirectories or files
find . -type d -exec chmod g+s '{}' \+

# Git object DB files are read-only
find .git/objects -type f -exec chmod ug=r '{}' \+
```

The last command is not strictly required. I just want to be extra pedantic.

Comment: I did the extra steps already. all dirs in it have correct permission 2775. Aso I did the `chmod -R g+rwX` before too. It worked at the beginning, no matter who did the git pull/commit for a while. Just after sometime, the .git/FETCH_HEAD become 644 and we do not know why

Comment: @Wang That requires investigation at your side — what command changes `.git/FETCH_HEAD` mode to 644? Perhaps you have to monitor the file after an every command for some time.

Comment: Worth pointing out, I think: `.git/FETCH_HEAD` is created by running `git fetch`. A server with `core.sharedRepository true` generally won't run `git fetch` *at all, ever*. Some external thing must be doing `cd path/to/repo && git fetch` or similar there. It's that operation that needs to be run with `umask 2`—or perhaps disabled entirely...

Comment: @torek thanks, this actually the problem I encountered, someone run git fetch with umask 22