# Is it possible to configure Git to set global write permissions when pushing to a filesystem remote?

Tags: git

Consider a git repository set up with a local filesystem remote, by user A as follows:

```
git init .
git remote add origin /var/git/my_project.git

touch X
git add X
git commit -m "My first commit"
git push origin master
```

If user B attempts to clone and then push, they will sometimes run into a permissions error because they cannot write to `/var/git/my_project.git`. User B could fix this by using sudo powers to change permissions on the remote:

```
sudo chmod 777 /var/git/my_project.git
```

Unfortunately, as soon as user B pushes, user A will have the same permissions problem.

**How can I configure Git for both user A and user B such that when they push to the local filesystem remote, they will leave the permissions globally writeable?**

(Note that I am aware of the security implications, but I am assuming only trusted users are able to login to the system in the first place.)

Comment: What are you using for the remote URL? SSH and they each have their own users?

Comment: The remote URL is `/var/git/my_project.git`. It's a local directory on the same machine.

Comment: If your server is on Linux, you can set default ACLs that automatically make every new file accessible to either a group of your choice, or the world.

Comment: @joanis It is running Linux. I'll try that, thanks!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69193032/7976758

Answer (score 1):

We were using a similar configuration at my office before moving to a GitLab server, and the way we solved it was to have default ACLs giving group read/write/execute to any new files created under the repo, initialized with ACLs granting those access on all files.

Repo access was controlled by membership in a linux group for the project, with the ACLs and default ACLs granting access to that group.

Answer (score 0):

Add both users to a `git` user group, change the repository files to be writable by that group.

Comment: And make sure you set the sticky bit, so new files are also writable. This solution might not always work, whereas I find default ACLs more robust.

Answer (score 0):

I have not tested it, but you could try to create the repository with the [`--shared`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-init#Documentation/git-init.txt---sharedfalsetrueumaskgroupallworldeverybody0xxx) option:

```
git init --shared=0777
```

Where, for example, `0777` represents the permissions in the octal format.

Comment: It looks like running `git config core.sharedRepository 0777` after the fact would also accomplish the same effect on a repo that already exists. Although it appears to affect only new files created in the repo after the setting is changed, so an up-front recursive chmod might be required.