# managing central git repo file permission

Tags: linux, git, file-permissions

I am being currently tasked with setting up a central git repo for my team.
We are in linux environment.

I created a new repo like this

```
cd aaa
git init --bare
cd ..
chmod -R 770 aaa
```

By doing so, I am actually controlling that only users that have the group permission is able to do a `git push`.

However, i noticed that, the objects that were `git push` by the users are basically owned by the users themselves, and not me (I am psginfra).

```
scc919025> tree -u aaa
aaa
├── [psginfra]  HEAD                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
├── [psginfra]  info                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
│   └── [psginfra]  exclude                                                                                                                                                                                                               
├── [psginfra]  objects                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
│   ├── [lionelta]  03                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
│   │   └── [lionelta]  e00cbf0a110c2a8d55f5e0109c40745f27c0f1
```

As you can see above from the `tree` command ran on the central git bare repo, the objects which are pushed by user `lionelta` is owned by him, and are protected by him.

When it comes to managing the central repo, I can not move the entire repo `aaa` around due to the permission issue.

My question is, is there a way of overcoming this? Or a Best Known Method to better manage a central bare repo, so that the admin can have more flexibility in moving around the repo?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Set `git config core.sharedRepository group` (or `0664`); see https://stackoverflow.com/a/69193032/7976758

Comment: Don't use `chmod -R 0770`, use `chmod -R g+w,o-rwx`. Otherwise you're pointlessly setting the `x` bit on ordinary files. It won't actually *hurt* Git itself, but it's ... sloppy and unnecessary.

Comment: Meanwhile: the usual modern method is to avoid giving this much raw power to individual users, usually via some fancy front end such as gitolite (20 years old now) or GitLab (much fancier, has lots of corporate goodies). That's kind of heavyweight, but it removes a lot of need-to-trust issues.