# Is there a way to git push without overriding the general permissions inside the .git folder (config, HEAD ecc.)?

Tags: git, ssh, permissions, pull

I'm working on a project with other colleagues, using Git to keep changes up to date.

Our testing environment is located on a university lab machine, which uses a secure environment to not allow people outside the Linux group to access these files, excluding us. We use ssh to log in with university credentials.

The problem lies when one of us pulls from the remote repo. When this happens, the permissions of some files inside the .git folder change, passing from those of the group to those of the individual, which makes it impossible for other members to pull into that environment, preventing testing until the person that you pulled last time, manually, changes all permissions to allow the entire Linux group to be able to make changes.

We tried to the command `git core.sharedrepository group`, and made sure each of us matched our git config email and username.

Any suggestions?

Comment: On the linux machine in question you could set the `s`ubstitute group id flag on `.git` and its subfolders, then new subfolders/files will inherit the group. (`find .git -type d -exec chmod g+rwxs {} +` `find .git -type f -exec chmod g+rw {} +`) See also https://superuser.com/questions/277775/ensuring-new-files-in-a-directory-belong-to-the-group ||| To also automatically set default group permissions (read/write/execute) bits on newly created subfolders/files, you can use acl/xattr like this: `find .git -type d -exec setfacl -Pdm g::rwx {} +`. `ls -l` will then show a `+` next to folder perms.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/69193032/7976758