# How to push to local git repo on seperate user without needing sudo

Tags: git, sudo

I've looked around and it seems I need to give my main user ownership of the files, but running chown on the files hasn't worked.

```
chown -R user:user /home/git/repos/repo
```

Here are the details for context.

I'm trying to push/pull from my main user to a bare git repo under user "git".
The link looks like this:

```
local /home/git/repos/repo (fetch/push)
```

Trying to push returns this error.

```
> git push local main
fatal: '/home/git/repos/repo' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

If I use sudo it works but it adds unwanted file permissions which cause issues when my acquaintance tries to push or pull remotely.

Comment: Make the repo group-shareable: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69193032/7976758